# How to resolve bootstrap not being applied on rails application developed on cloud9 ide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, cloud9-ide

I'm a beginner in developing applications using Ruby on Rails and I'm currently signed up and using Cloud9 as my development IDE.

I've created my first Rails project without a hitch and I'm following a tutorial on how to create a Rails website applying bootstrap.

I've installed the necessary gems `bootstrap-sass` and `autoprefixer-rails`, renamed my `application.css` to `application.css.scss`, added `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` & `@import "bootstrap"`, added `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to `application.js` and added a navbar copied directly from the bootstrap homepage.

The tutorial I've been following is this youtube tutorial video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v002f5-9hx8

The problem is that after saving all changes and even after restarting my rails server, bootstrap never seems to be applied and I can't get it to work in my application. Any insights on this problem which may help me to resolve it. I've been trying to search google but it seems that it's a rare case so I can't find any good information to solve this problem.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?  I believe if you are on Rails 4.2, it should be very easy to add Bootstrap.

Comment: In `application.js` change the directive to `//= require bootstrap`.

Comment: You may need `gem 'sass-rails'` (I use version 5.0.1).  Not sure if it is causing an issue, but I don't think you should change `application.css` - just add a new file like `custom.css.scss` to the same folder and put the two import commands there.

Comment: Ruby && Rails version:

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities for your issue, however, we dont have enough info to help.  Useful info would be: Rails version, ruby version, a quick look at your gem-file etc.

For the interim, just use these CDN's in your application.html.erb file in the layouts.

CSS: `<link rel='stylesheet' href="ttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

JS: `<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>`

Things to definitely check:

- Gemfile syntax (http://bundler.io/gemfile.html)
- Whether your config file (application.css/js files)for the asset pipeline is set-up correctly.
- If you have any simple syntax issues anywhere. (I know, this is redundant.)